# Remove unrelated terms from view's filter criteria (tag list filtering)

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a content type with four main categories. Users can reach each main category from links.  These links are pointing to the default **"/taxonomy/term/%"** view. There are two filters that exposed to visitors. Filter by name and tag. My problem is that tag dropdown shows all tags, even those that belong to other main category. How can I limit the list to show only the available tags from the current view? Is there a module for this?

*Example:*

**Contents**

Name / Category / Tags (separated with **"+"** sign)

1. Drupal / PHP / cms+modular+complex
2. Wordpress / PHP / cms+modular+blog
3. Codeigniter / PHP / mvc+framework
4. Django / Python / great+python+framework

If I visit either the page that lists PHP or either Python category, the tag filter criteria shows all existing tags:

**cms+modular+complex+blog+mvx+framework+great+python**

However on the PHP page it should only show me:

**cms+modular+complex+blog+mvx+framework** (because "great" and "python" are not related to any PHP content.

This means Python page should allow me to choose only from:

**great+python+framework** ("framework" appearing in PHP too but that doesn't matter as the page already filter it to only Python category)

Comment: Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: @Mathankumar Yes, I edited my question to show you an example. I only used two main categories to keep it simple. I hope you'll understand it now. Thank you!